# Is there a maintained immutable priority queue in Scala?

Tags: scala, immutability, priority-queue, scala-2.8

I am looking for an implementation of an immutable priority queue for at least Scala 2.8, but preferably more current. Is there a good implementation somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some links here: http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/10374

In particular, see https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/FingerTree.scala and https://github.com/Sciss/FingerTree

I think you can trust the code in scalaz to be sound. If you want a lighter-weight library, you can examine the source code from Sciss and see what you think.